# Keycloak impersonation

Tags: keycloak, impersonation

The keycloak admin panel provides the functionality to impersonate a user of a realm, which results in a redirect to the account client (/account) "impersonated" for this user. This for example allows an admin to change the email, firstname etc. of a user.

Is it possible to also impersonate a user "at a" client of the realm. For example a backend with a rest-api which is "secured" by keylcoak?

....or this inly possible with the [Token Exchange impersonation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#impersonation) ?